# Email of Managed Metadata term shows horrible number in SPD

Tags: sharepoint-designer

If you want to display the value of a Managed Metadata column in a SharePoint Designer workflow, you get a horrible representation of it like ‘TermText|ba7e2a4f-6602-47a8-aa81-bca54756a356′.

I'm emailing out the tag using [%Current Item:MyTag]. is there a way I can remove the trailing hex digits ?

I've looked at the 'Utility Actions' but doesnt seem to be possible, can i write my own string manipulation ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Marc D Anderson explains this on his blog: 
[Displaying Managed Metadata Column Values in an Email Sent from a SharePoint Designer Workflow](http://sympmarc.com/2012/11/09/displaying-managed-metadata-column-values-in-an-email-sent-from-a-sharepoint-designer-workflow/)

Extract from blog:

> Managed Metadata columns are so cool and so nasty at the same time. If
> you want to display the value of a Managed Metadata column in a
> SharePoint Designer workflow, you get a horrible representation of it
> like ‘TermText|ba7e2a4f-6602-47a8-aa81-bca54756a356′.
>
> The only
> solution I know for this is the one in the comment from Kristina P on
> Michal Pisarek’s (@MichalPisarek) blog post [Managed Metadata Column
> Limitations](http://www.sharepointanalysthq.com/2011/06/managed-metadata-column-limitations/) (a post which I find myself referring to far too
> regularly).
>
> Here’s the meat of it:
>
> Start with your managed metadata column (Column1Name)
>
> Create a 2nd column (Column2Name) in the list of type string
>
> Create a workflow that fires on create and/or on modify (depending on your needs) that copies the value from Column1Name into Column2Name.
>
> Create a 3rd calculated column (Column3Name) on the list. The formula for that column should be =LEFT([Column2Name],FIND(“|”,[Column2Name])-1) The calculation finds the pipe character and trims the value to a clean text value.
>
> Any emails where you need to display the value of Column1Name should use the value of Column3Name instead to send the plain text

Comment: Hi is there any other option. I was hoping to find a solution in SPD and not create extra columns. Thanks

Comment: Wait for other answers, if not I guess this is the only option!

Comment: HI I found a way to extend SPD but require a wsp for 2010. When I port it creates a dll not wsp. 
Any ideas on where to get a ported version from or to create a wsp ?
 
http://spdwfextensions.codeplex.com/
 
Thanks

Comment: @RajChahal instead of extending, you can simply add calculated columns, this will be more feasible solution!

Comment: I would be interested to hear views from others also on this issue. Thanks

Comment: When I try this, I get "The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported." :(

Comment: try your formula on excel sheet, SharePoint calculated column formula's are just like Excel sheet formulas.. so you can try and remove errors in Excel first